# NetLogo: line break in output file?? Not so simple.

Tags: file, line-breaks, netlogo

I tried all options to create a new line in my output file, but still I get a txt-file with everything behind the previous information. Even with this supersimple code:

globals [file]

```
to setup   clear-all
    set file "results\\GA1.txt"   if is-string? file
     [while [file-exists? file]
        [set file replace-item (length file - 5) file "11" ]
      file-open file] end

to go   tick   write-to-file end

to write-to-file   file-print (word ticks) FILE-TYPE "\n"   file-write 1 file-print (word " " 2 ";")   file-write 1 file-print (word " " 2 ";")     file-print ""  ;; blank line end
```

I do not get blank lines or line breaks. I work in NetLogo 4.1. Does anybody know what could be the problem?

Answer (score 4):

answered at http://netlogo-users.18673.x6.nabble.com/Adding-a-new-line-when-outputting-data-tp4870905p4870909.html where I wrote:

> Are you on Windows and using Notepad to view your files? Nearly every
>   other Windows program these days understands Unix-style line breaks,
>   but Notepad doesn't.

Comment: yahoo blocks users without an account, it's better to add answers here directly

Comment: @tong: good point. replaced with Nabble URL for the same post

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to close the file with `file-close` or to force it to write data to disk with a `file-flush`.

When you do a `file-write` the data does not get written to disk immediately. It gets placed in a buffer. When the buffer is large enough the data is written to disk. You can force netlogo to write data to a file by using the `file-flush` or `file-close` commands.

Answer (score 2):

The reference suggests using a better editor. But there is a way to make Notepad work.

If you add the string "\r\n" to your data (with file-type or whatever), it works with Notepad.

Notepad uses the older carriage return ("\r")/ new line ("\n") format. The Unix systems just use new line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this works for me

```
file-open "locations.txt"
   ask turtles
   [file-print xcor]
file-close
```

if you want more breaks, then use this

```
file-open "locations.txt"
   ask turtles
   [file-print xcor file-print "\n"]
file-close
```