# file-print doesn't seem to work in ask

Tags: netlogo

```
breed[inboxturtles inboxturtle]
to check
  create-inboxturtles 100[setxy random-xcor random-ycor] 
  file-open "D:\\hello.csv"
  file-write "X Coordinate" file-write "," file-write "Y Coordinate" file-write "," 
  file-write "Who" file-print ""
      ask inboxturtles [ 
        file-print ""
        file-write xcor file-write ","
        file-write ycor file-write ","
        file-write who 
        ]  
  file-close
  end
```

I don't know `file-print` doesn't work in `ask` but it works outside it certainly. Can someone help me, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The code looks correct to me. What evidence do you have that it doesn't work? What does the resulting file look like?

Comment: There was problem with my editor in Windows for the issue.

Comment: Ah, duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3455089/86485 then

Comment: @SethTisue Yes, you're right. I noticed it afterwards. But the answers also correct my mistake of incorrectly writing to the file using file-write. I guess that should help others as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine for me:

```
 "X Coordinate" "," "Y Coordinate" "," "Who"

 -11.273903984790302 "," 11.589865065737627 "," 60
 -3.198704310517442 "," -2.327808927515365 "," 6
 13.485197306065764 "," -3.747989432973762 "," 91
 16.085782333733263 "," 13.530031781112555 "," 35
 ...
```

By the way, you should use [`file-type`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#file-type) instead of [`file-write`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#file-write) for writing to a file without appending a newline.

`file-write` does weird things like putting quotes around all strings (that's why the commas are quotes in the above output).

Better yet, you should use [`word`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#word) to concatenate strings instead of `file-write` (or `file-type`) over and over. I would write the above code like so:

```
to check
  create-inboxturtles 100[setxy random-xcor random-ycor] 
  file-open "D:\\hello.csv"
  file-print "X Coordinate,Y Coordinate,Who"
  ask inboxturtles [
    file-print (word xcor "," ycor "," who) 
  ]  
  file-close
end
```

This outputs:

```
X Coordinate,Y Coordinate,Who
-5.409837709344972,-0.6301891295194455,165
15.024747417946124,-9.591123025568086,193
9.735972095912903,-3.935540025692582,176
-11.505336629875304,-12.082889705829679,103
-10.19902536584426,-14.86360155896942,85
-5.928287603043071,7.175770417278386,22
-10.538908046584938,-15.009427435006804,120
...
```

which is probably more what you want. By the way, in CSV it's okay to have spaces in strings without putting quotes around them. The only time you need quotes is when the strings themselves contain commas.

Finally, note that if the file already exists, it will just be appended to rather than overwritten. So you may want something like `if file-exists? filename [ file-delete filename ]` before `file-open`.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the detailed answer. There was problem with my editor in Windows for the issue I asked. Your other advice really helped too! Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Use `file-type` instead.  If you really want quotes around the strings, you can add them.

```
breed[inboxturtles inboxturtle]

to check
  file-open "c:/temp/temp.csv"
  file-type xcor 
  file-type "," file-type ycor 
  file-type "," file-type who 
  file-print ""
  file-close
end

to setup
  ca
  carefully [file-delete "C:/temp/temp.csv"] []
  file-open "C:/temp/temp.csv"
  file-type "\"X Coordinate\"" 
  file-type "," file-type "\"Y Coordinate\"" 
  file-type "," 
  file-type "\"Who\"" 
  file-print ""
  file-close
  create-inboxturtles 100[setxy random-xcor random-ycor] 
end

to go
  ask inboxturtles [check]
end
```